# Is there a GUI library that works with the Intel Perceptual Computing SDK?

Tags: c++, intel, gestures, perceptual-sdk

I am looking for a GUI library to design the interface for my application. Are there any libraries that work well with the Intel Perceptual Computing SDK?

Comment: +1 I'm curious to hear what you chose in the end. On a side note, check my answer when you have the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any GUI library that is available for Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 or later and runs on Microsoft Windows 7 or later should work well.

If you want GUI that works both on Linux and Windows then for example Qt. It can 
be integrated with MSVC++.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise you to use [QT](http://qt-project.org/) framework. It is cross-platform and runs on the major desktop platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my demo **[ipcQTgesture](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/tree/master/ipcQTgesture)** hosted at github.

The GUI is very simple and it is created with **Qt**. Even though **Qt** is cross-platform framework for building graphical applications, the *Intel® Perceptual Computing SDK* is not, so for the moment we are stuck to Windows.